# Apache2 Proxy Changing HTML

Tags: proxy, apache2, doctype

We have Apache2 proxy runing on Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS and have noticed the DOCTYPE gets removed in every served page.  Also, some CSS font settings are ignored.  Our webserver is running Win 2008 R2.  Is there a way to tell Apache to serve the pages as is and bypass any modifications?

Any suggestions or recommendations would be most appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Ubuntu Apache has a ProxyPass entry to the webserver on the windows machine?

Comment: Yes, believe so but I'm very new to Apache.  Would you like to see any config directives?

Comment: Try the steps in my answer, this can prove that the ubuntu server really changes the response.

Answer (score 0):

imo ProxyPass don't change something. but to be sure you can capture the net traffic with tcpdump replace the place holder with the ip address of your windows webserver.
After you do a request to the ubuntu webserver and see the response from windows machine in your browser stop tcpdump (ctrl+c) and check test.log with wireshark.

```
sudo tcpdump -A -n -s 0 -w test.log port 80 and host HTTPD_ON_WINDOWS
```

Comment: Looks promising but let me see if I understand correctly.

1) Log onto the Proxy Server and execute the command: sudo tcpdump -A -n -s 0 -w test.log port 80 and host HTTPD_ON_WINDOWS

2) Open the website in IE.

3) On the Proxy Server, stop tcpdump and view test.log with "wireshark".

Is this correct?

Comment: That's right. If you have problems to read 'test.log' can I take a look at it.